# Google Apps Script: How to automatically copy documents to a new folder?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a script for my classes that will copy 2 files (templates) as soon as I create a folder. Something like this:

1. Create new folder /new_student/ in the folder Google_drive/customer_class_b/
2. Copy the files student_guidelines.gdoc and student_acknowledgement.gdoc from Google_drive/resources to Google_drive/customer_class_b/
3. Rename the files student_guidelines.gdoc and student_acknowledgement.gdoc to student_guidelines_class_b.gdoc and student_acknowledgement_class_b.gdoc

Result should be having 2 files: Google_drive/customer_class_b/student_guidelines_class_b.gdoc and Google_drive/customer_class_b/student_acknowledgement_class_b.gdoc

I tried to play with the scripts but I am struggling. Any idea of how we could do so?

Comment: Please be more specific. Can you write some code that you have tried. It will be helpful to understand your problem

Comment: I am really not a coder so I am not sure it would be of any help if I copy what I tried, sorry :| Even declaring the functions is a struggle...

Answer (score 3):

As @Vasim said, we can help you better if you provided some code or error code that you encountered.

From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy()), you can copy a file using the [`makeCopy()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy()) method; [`makeCopy(destination)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopydestination) to copy the file in the destination directory; [`makeCopy(name)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname) to create a copy of the file and names it with the name provided; and [`makeCopy(name, destination)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname-destination) to copy the file in the destination directory and names it with the name provided.

Here is an example from [Google apps script examples - Copy file and move to another folder](http://gasforga.blogspot.com/2015/06/google-apps-script-examples-google-apps.html):

```
function copyfile() {
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1pkwQ9te-EtpqC_NC3BoHzOTUoC7axZDcAfxrqMgslwg");
var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B8_ub-Gf21e-fkxjSUwtczJGb3picl9LUVVPbnV6Vy1aRFRWc21IVjRkRjBPTV9xMWJLRFU")
var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B8_ub-Gf21e-flJ4VmxvaWxmM2NpZHFyWWxRejE5Y09CRWdIZDhDQzBmU2JnZnhyMTU2ZHM")
// Make a backup copy.
var file2 = file.makeCopy('BACKUP ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') + '.' + file.getName());
dest_folder.addFile(file2);
source_folder.removeFile(file2);
}
```

You can check on these related threads:

- [Make a Copy of Folders in Google Drive with Google Scripts](https://ctrlq.org/code/19979-copy-folders-drive)
- [How to copy a file into a specific folder using DocsList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328247/how-to-copy-a-file-into-a-specific-folder-using-docslist)
- [How do I copy & move a file to a folder in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696514/how-do-i-copy-move-a-file-to-a-folder-in-google-apps-script)

Hope this helps!