# Creating zip file only contains pdf

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In my script I am trying to create a folder, create a date-stamped-document in said folder, create a sub folder, and copy some documents into that sub folder.

All of this works great. When I try to zip the parent folder via either of the methods found here: [Creating a zip file inside google drive with apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259041/creating-a-zip-file-inside-google-drive-with-apps-script) - it creates a zip file with a sole PDF file that has the same name as the date-stamped-document. The zipped PDF is blank, and the subfolder isn't there.

Any insight about why this is happening would be great.

```
var folder = DocsList.createFolder(folderTitle);
var subFolder = folder.createFolder('Attachments');
    subfolder.createFile(attachments[]); //In a loop that creates a file from every
                                         //attachment from messages in thread

var doc = DocumentApp.create(docTitle); //Google Doc
var docLocation = DocsList.getFileById(doc.getId());
    docLocation.addToFolder(folder);
    docLocation.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
//Everything works fine, I can view file and subfolder, and subfolder's documents

//This is where the problem is:
var zippedFolder = DocsList.getFolder(folder.getName());
    zippedFolder.createFile(Utilities.zip(zippedFolder.getFiles(), 'newFiles.zip'));
//this results in a zipped folder containing one blank pdf that has the same title as doc
```

Comment: Can you post the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great question. It does not seem that the zip function has the ability to zip sub folders. The reason that your script doesn't work is because you only select the *files* from the folder.

A solution would be to zip each of the subfolders and store that in the one zipped file. You can use the function that I wrote for this.

```
function zipFolder(folder) {
  var zipped_folders = [];
  var folders = folder.getFolders();
  for(var i in folders)
    zipped_folders.push(zipFolder(folders[i]));
  return Utilities.zip(folder.getFiles().concat(zipped_folders),folder.getName()+".zip");
}
```

This recursively zips all subfolders. Then you need to create the file with something like

```
DocsList.getFolder("path/to/folder/to/store/zip/file").createFile(zipFolder(folderToZip));
```

I will put in a feature request to allow subfolders to be zipped.

Comment: It works! I didn't even have to modify the structure. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The DocsList service has been deprecated so Phil Bozak's previous solution no longer works.  However, refer to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237799/zip-multiple-folders-in-1-zip-google-drive-scripts?rq=1) for solution that works with DriveApp class.