# Create password protected zip file in google apps/drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Does anyone know a way to create a password protected zip file much as I could in 7zip but using a Google Apps script.  I can create an unprotected zip using this script: [Creating a zip file...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259041/creating-a-zip-file-inside-google-drive-with-apps-script)

However, we need to send a CSV file containing confidential info to our contractor and the conditions of our service require it to be zipped and password protected.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there no password in [Google class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities) yet implemented you have to encrypt file before zipping and provide customer with decode utility. Meanwhile [submit request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) to Google.

Comment: Still true in 2019?