# How to set password for file in Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I sent a link file via mail to someone in the google app script. I want to ask is there any way to set password for file in google app script? When users enter the link will ask to enter the password.
(sorry, my english is not good)

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474489/create-password-protected-zip-file-in-google-apps-drive), there is no password in [Google class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities) yet implemented. You can file this as feature request in this [link](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).