# Zip large files in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create an archive system built into Google Apps Script. I want to be able to zip a large folder that is already in Google Drive without having to download anything.

I've tried the following code:

```js
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(<FOLDER_ID>);
folder.createFile(Utilities.zip(folder.getFiles(), 'newFiles.zip'));
```

This correctly zips folders, but when I try to run it on larger folders, it throws this error after running for a while:

> Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property zip on object Utilities.
> at zipping(Code:172:24)
> at ZipFolder.zip(Code:30:22)
> at zip(Code:9:66)

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What is is ZipFolder? Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a zip file inside Google Drive with Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259041/creating-a-zip-file-inside-google-drive-with-apps-script)

Comment: Oops. I posted the wrong code on accident. I've updated it now.